# Use of dereference operator in this example (c++)

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

I don't understand why, in this example, i cannot access a member function by dereferencing the object

Here it's the relevant part of the code

```
class Search
{
public:
void run();

private:
Result* result;
Result* extractResults()
};
```

the extractResults() is defined as follows

```
Result* Search::extractResults()
{
Result* ris;
//as soon as i know the size, i initialize ris
ris = new Result[numOfResults];
return ris;
}
```

Inside the run() function, i call extractResults to get a pointer to the internal ris object

```
result = extractResults();
```

Now, i would expect to be able to access the "result" object, inside run(), like this:

```
result[4]->doSomething();
```

But it doesn't work, i must use

```
result[4].doSomething();
```

Why is that?

**EDIT**

Ok, i modified the code in order to be able to use the dereferencing operator. I know it is not necessary to use pointers in this situation, i just used it as an exercise.

```
class Search
{
public:
void run();

private:
Result** resultPP;
Result* resultP;
Result* extractResults()
};

Result* Search::extractResults()
{
Risultato* ris;
//as soon as i know the size, i initialize ris
ris = new Risultato[numOfResults];
return ris;
}
```

Inside the run() function

```
resultP = extractResults();
resultPP = &resultP;
```

Now i can finally do:

```
resultPP->doSomething();
```

I know it's messy, i just wanted to do it like this, as a way of learning.
thanks!

Comment: Because result[4] doesnt return a pointer, its a reference to an element of the array. (In this case result[4] is equivalent to `*(result + 4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result` is a pointer to an array of `Risultato`. Therefore the objects inside of `result` are actually value types. If you really wanted to use the dereferencing operator you would have to declare `result` as a pointer to an array of pointers to `Resultato`. I hope that helps.